# PowerShell - Add string between outputs

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to separate by a string (;), results from this :

```
$MasterKeys = ($MasterKeys | Where {$_.Name -ne $Null -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null} | select-String Name,Version,ComputerName | sort Name| ft -hide )
```

Here is the output of this command:

```
HP ePrint SW 5.1.20088 LT00438
```

I would like this instead:

```
HP ePrint SW; 5.1.20088; LT00438
```

Well, this is the full code :
I don't know where to put the `Export-Csv -Path "file.txt" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation` function :(

```
Function Get-InstalledSoftware
{
    Param
    (
        [Alias('Computer','ComputerName','HostName')]
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$True,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true,Position=1)]
        [string[]]$Name = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    )
    Begin
    {
        $LMkeys = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall","SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        $LMtype = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine
        $CUkeys = "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall"
        $CUtype = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::CurrentUser

    }
    Process
    {
        ForEach($Computer in $Name)
        {
            $MasterKeys = @()
            If(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -count 1 -quiet))
            {
                Write-Error -Message "Unable to contact $Computer. Please verify its network connectivity and try again." -Category ObjectNotFound -TargetObject $Computer
                Break
            }
            $CURegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($CUtype,$computer)
            $LMRegKey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($LMtype,$computer)
            ForEach($Key in $LMkeys)
            {
                $RegKey = $LMRegKey.OpenSubkey($key)
                If($RegKey -ne $null)
                {
                    ForEach($subName in $RegKey.getsubkeynames())
                    {
                        foreach($sub in $RegKey.opensubkey($subName))
                        {
                            $MasterKeys += (New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                            "ComputerName" = $Computer
                            "Name" = $sub.getvalue("displayname")
                            "SystemComponent" = $sub.getvalue("systemcomponent")
                            "ParentKeyName" = $sub.getvalue("parentkeyname")
                            "Version" = $sub.getvalue("DisplayVersion")
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ForEach($Key in $CUKeys)
            {
                $RegKey = $CURegKey.OpenSubkey($Key)
                If($RegKey -ne $null)
                {
                    ForEach($subName in $RegKey.getsubkeynames())
                    {
                        foreach($sub in $RegKey.opensubkey($subName))
                        {
                            $MasterKeys += (New-Object PSObject -Property @{
                            "ComputerName" = $Computer
                            "Name" = $sub.getvalue("displayname")
                            "SystemComponent" = $sub.getvalue("systemcomponent")
                            "ParentKeyName" = $sub.getvalue("parentkeyname")
                            "Version" = $sub.getvalue("DisplayVersion")
                            })
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            $files = "inventaireLT.txt" 
            $MasterKeys = ($MasterKeys | Where {$_.Name -ne $Null -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null} | select Name,Version,ComputerName | sort Name| ft -hide )
            $MasterKeys >> $files


        }
    }
    End
    { 

    }
}
Clear-Content -path $files 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -LDAPfilter "(name=LT*)" -SearchBase "OU=S****Y,DC=T***R,DC=com" | Get-InstalledSoftware


(gc inventaireLT.txt) | ? {$_.trim() -ne "" } | set-content inventaireLT.txt
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the semicolon separated output? Export it to a file or pass it onto further code?

Comment: I suspect you want `Select-Object -Property ...` instead of `Select-String`. What does `$MasterKeys` look like?

Comment: @James C. With these semicolon separated output, I wan to import it to a homemade software. It's perfectly working when I add manualy the semicolon. But it's impossible to do it manualy for the all file, I have like 5000 lines :(

Comment: @Jeff Zeitlin The ouput of $MasterKeys looks like to this : HP ePrint SW 5.1.20088 LT00438

Comment: Hello. Try to replace this select-String Name,Version,ComputerName on this:
Select -property @{n="name";e={$_.name + " ;"}}, @{n="Version";e={$_.Version + " ;"}}, ComputerName

Comment: Is `$MasterKeys` a string, an array of strings, or a structured type? How is it being generated in the first place? In other words, how does PowerShell know what the Name, the Versions, or the Computer are?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin From the code, it must be an object with `Name`, `SystemComponent`, `ParentKeyName `, `Version` and `ComputerName` as (some kind of) properties.

Comment: @gms0ulman - That would be my assumption as well; however, the report of what it looks like doesn't clearly indicate this, and the querent was (mis?)using `Select-String` in xir original code.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Good point. `Select-Object` would be more appropriate.

Comment: @gms0ulman - ... provided that the original data (`$MasterKeys`) is properly structured - which it's still not clear is the case.

Comment: I'm pretty sure `$MasterKeys` is coming from the registry as the keys match those in `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall ` and the example also points towards this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export your data to a semicolon separated file by using `Export-Csv` and specifying the `-Delimiter ";"`

```
$MasterKeys | Where {$_.Name -ne $Null -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null} | select Name,Version,ComputerName | Export-Csv -Path "C:\folder\file.txt" -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation
```

If you don't want the header line:

```
$MasterKeys | Where {$_.Name -ne $Null -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null} |
select Name,Version,ComputerName |  
ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation |
Select-Object -Skip 1 |
Set-Content -Path "C:\folder\file.txt"
```

---

**EDIT:**

In your code you would replace:

```
$MasterKeys = ($MasterKeys | Where {$_.Name -ne $Null -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null} | select Name,Version,ComputerName | sort Name| ft -hide )
$MasterKeys >> $files
```

with

```
$MasterKeys | Where {$_.Name -ne $Null -AND $_.SystemComponent -ne "1" -AND $_.ParentKeyName -eq $Null} | select Name,Version,ComputerName | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter ";" -NoTypeInformation | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content -Path $files
```

Comment: Thank you ! It's working perfectly ! Just be careful, after -NoTypeInformation) you have to remove the "(", otherwise the script doens't work :)

Comment: Sorry, that `(` is a copy and paste error on my part.

Comment: Ho just realized, the ouput is correct but it'deleting previous lines at every loop. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: I think you would just need to change `Set-Content` to `Add-Content`

Comment: Oh yes great :D Thank you for this great help !